# Loading js files for each page dynamically using _ViewStart in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, typescript, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm working on a project using ASP.NET Core 6 Razor pages.

The `*.ts` files located in the `Script` directory and compiler will put the output in `wwwroot/js/`.

My goal is to load each of these `.js` files for pages with the same name, for example if my page name is `index.cshtml`, it should load the `index.js` file automatically.

So far I've done this in my `_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```cs
var pageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path);
var jsFile = "~/js/" + pageName + ".js";
//some how load the jsFile
```

but the problem is that the `jsFile` is always "_ViewStart", I need some how get the name of the file that is using `_ViewStart` at the moment (like if `index.cshtml` is loading for user and it's rendering `_ViewStart`, I need to get the `index.cshtml`) and viewbags are really bad, they are easy to forget and mess with typos, I need something safer.

I think I can achieve the same using reflection in my application startup (appending the `<script>` at the bottom of each `*.cshtml` file maybe?), but it's a bit nasty, I guess.

Sorry if this is a long or bad question

Comment: Why don't you specify which script to load using @section? That will load scripts for the current page.

Comment: @MikeBrind i dont want to do it manually, lets say i have 30 pages, it would be a pain to load them one by one, i think its more efficient to automate this process

Comment: I'm not sure if there is another method without using reflection, But after I searching a lot, I don't find any useful method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current page's file name from the Endpoint data for the current page.  For example, in _Layout.cshtml, you can do the following:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
@inject IWebHostEnvironment environment
@{
    var endpoint = Context.GetEndpoint() as RouteEndpoint;
    var jsFile = endpoint?.Metadata.OfType<PageActionDescriptor>().FirstOrDefault()?.ViewEnginePath.Trim('/');
    var fileExists = jsFile is not null ? File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(environment.WebRootPath, "js", jsFile + ".js")) : false;
}
```

Then, at the point you want to inject the script:

```
@if(fileExists)
{
    <script src="~/js/@(jsFile).js"></script>
}
```